# Facebook FQL. Which is the easiest way to get all page changes in one single query ordered by date/time?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I need to monitor one single page and all related activities. This is the result I'm trying to accomplish:

```
29/10 - User: John - Action: Like    - Object type: status - Object id: 123456
29/10 - User: Mary - Action: Comment - Object type: status - Object id: 123343
29/10 - User: Etan - Action: Tagged  - Object type: status - Object id: 123537
29/10 - User: Arth - Action: Like    - Object type: status - Object id: 123876
29/10 - User: Jack - Action: Post    - Object type: status - Object id: 123423
29/10 - User: Jack - Action: Photo   - Object type: photo - Object id: 123423
```

You can take as example the search by term, that provide everything as expected. We have in one single call comments, posts, statuses and photos ordered since the specified date/time:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post

Since there's no way to do it simple as the `/search?q=`, how can I do it with FQL?

Should I use the `stream` table? In that case, which filter of the `stream_table` should I apply?

Is there an easy way to do that or do I have to get every thing in separated queries?

(If it helps: I'm using Facebook PHP SDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are also using this technique but there is still an issue. The stream table returns the **Top Posts** view of the feed and not the **Most recent** one EVEN if you specify an **ORDER BY updated_time DESC**.

So you might miss posts, especially posts from fans.
We have not found a solution to this problem...

Comment: Recently, I've open a similar bug. See: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/216294328439854

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem recently. Initially I thought that the `feed` connection of a page will be what I need, but it turns out that if you sort with `since` or `until` it will look at a post's `created_at` attribute. This means that comments on older posts won't show up.

The best solution I could find is to first do a FQL query on the `stream` table to get the post ids:

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = {PAGE_ID} AND updated_time > {TIME}
```

and then simply get all the posts at once:

```
https://graph.facebook.com?ids=ID1,ID2,ID3...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it. I first thought that it needed the stream_filter too.