# php sdk - Facebook to gather fan page posts

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am trying to gather the last posts on my fan page to update on my website using the php SDK, I have the following code but it returns an empty array, is there something I am missing? It doesn't seem obvious to me how this won't work, I have tried for literally days now and still get no further following other tutorials etc..

```
require_once("fcbk/facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '********';
$config['secret'] = '*********';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$pageid = "*********";
$pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed");
var_dump($pagefeed);
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue, people seem to have solved it here :

Solutions is basically use FQL to filter last entries, get each post_id and retrieve each post usind another call passing all these IDs

check this post here :

[Facebook FQL. Which is the easiest way to get all page changes in one single query ordered by date/time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942771/facebook-fql-which-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-all-page-changes-in-one-single-que)

it worked for me.